# Pandas how to align left multi-levels columns?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

A picture is worth a thousand words.

Note: I just want to align visually rather than logically.

[image]

Comment: @AnuragDabas Not works, your code just swap the `A` and `AA` position, does not align to left.

Comment: can you post your code as text(`df.head.to_dict()`) and expected output from it?

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes.

Comment: @HenryEcker `MultiIndex([( 'A', 'close'),
            ( 'A',  'high'),
            ( 'A',   'low'),
            ( 'A',  'open'),
            ( 'A',   'vol'),
            ('AA', 'close'),
            ('AA',  'high'),
            ('AA',   'low'),
            ('AA',  'open'),
            ('AA',   'vol')],
           )`

Comment: do you want to append `df_list[1]` in `df_list[0]`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas Sorry, I forget add the `axis=1`, I update the picture, but it's not effect the result.

Comment: @HenryEcker JupyterLab `3.0.16`.

Comment: Okay how about setting a styler like: `df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('text-align', 'left')]}])`

Comment: @HenryEcker Not works, no effect.

Comment: Your question is vague, please add a bit of text to explain what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1):

- clearly you want to treat OHLC as a categorical so that you can define sort order
- re-construct **column** index using `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays()`
- within this define OHLC as a sorted categorical
- then `sort_index()` **columns** which uses defined categorical sort order

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# construct a multi-index DF
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "date": np.random.choice(pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=5), 500),
            "rating": np.random.choice(["A", "AA"], 500),
            "ohlc": np.random.choice(["open", "close", "high", "low"], 500),
            "price": np.random.uniform(3, 5, 500),
        }
    )
    .sort_values(["date", "rating", "ohlc"])
    .set_index(["date", "rating", "ohlc"])
)

# reshape to same as "picture"
df2 = df.groupby(by=["date", "rating", "ohlc"]).mean().unstack(["rating", "ohlc"])

print(df2.to_string())

# redefine columns as categoricals so sort_index() works
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [
        df2.columns.get_level_values("rating"),
        pd.CategoricalIndex(
            df2.columns.get_level_values("ohlc"),
            ordered=True,
            categories=["open", "high", "low", "close"],
        ),
    ]
)
# finally sort the columns...
df2.sort_index(axis=1)

print(df2.sort_index(axis=1).to_string())
```

#### before sort

```
               price                                                                      
rating             A                                      AA                              
ohlc           close      high       low      open     close      high       low      open
date                                                                                      
2021-01-01  3.812598  4.270862  3.804053  3.927815  3.807602  4.033908  3.989067  4.169900
2021-01-02  3.950977  3.798957  4.053549  3.885642  4.071506  4.091227  3.996981  4.179648
2021-01-03  4.130155  4.311536  4.072253  3.763274  4.238135  3.928009  3.898514  3.677661
2021-01-04  4.000603  4.211852  4.178882  4.112401  3.775267  4.224650  3.955743  4.150286
2021-01-05  3.902104  3.793516  3.973869  3.772823  3.980795  4.058692  4.007785  3.736026
```

#### after sort

```
rating             A                                      AA                              
ohlc            open      high       low     close      open      high       low     close
date                                                                                      
2021-01-01  3.927815  4.270862  3.804053  3.812598  4.169900  4.033908  3.989067  3.807602
2021-01-02  3.885642  3.798957  4.053549  3.950977  4.179648  4.091227  3.996981  4.071506
2021-01-03  3.763274  4.311536  4.072253  4.130155  3.677661  3.928009  3.898514  4.238135
2021-01-04  4.112401  4.211852  4.178882  4.000603  4.150286  4.224650  3.955743  3.775267
2021-01-05  3.772823  3.793516  3.973869  3.902104  3.736026  4.058692  4.007785  3.980795
```